# OData & WCF : Unable to perform POST,PUT & DELETE

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio, wcf-data-services, odata

I have configured & built **WCF and oData with Visual Studio 2012** using [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m51wIoMk2XM) tutorial.

So I have used **Firefox REST Client plugin** to test whether its working fine or not.

Here is my base URL which is dealing with json, `192.168.1.4/TestdataService/TestDataService.svc/User?$format=json`

I can do **GET** operation successfully. However I'm unable to perform **POST,PUT & DELETE** operations.

**POST** operation says

> Status Code: 415 Unsupported Media Type

Its **responds body** is

```
 {
  "odata.error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en-US",
      "value": "Unsupported media type requested."
    }
  }
}
```

**PUT & DELETE** operations says

> Status Code: 405 Method
>
> Not Allowed Allow: GET, POST

Its **responds body** is

```
{
  "odata.error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en-US",
      "value": "The URI 'http://192.168.1.4/TestdataService/TestDataService.svc/User?$format=json' is not valid for DELETE operation. The URI must refer to a single resource from an entity set or from a property referring to a set of resources."
    }
  }
}
```

I'm attaching the screenshots below. Any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks.

**GET**
[image]

**POST**
[image]

[image]

[image]

**PUT**
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show an example of the message body for the put/post requests?

Comment: @qujck: I have added  message body screen shots..

Comment: Unfortunately the screen shots do not appear in my browser (I think our proxy server must block them)

Comment: oh...for POST it displays {"odata.error":{"code":"","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Unsupported media type requested."}}}

Comment: for PUT its says {"odata.error":{"code":"","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The URI 'http://192.168.1.4/TestdataService/TestDataService.svc/User?$format=json' is not valid for PUT operation. The URI must point to a single resource for PUT operations."}}}

Comment: those are the message *responses*, what about the *requests*?

Comment: I just put the same structure for all... "http://192.168.1.4/TestdataService/TestDataService.svc/User?$format=json"

Comment: You're probably missing an identifier in the URI for DELETE and PUT: `TestDataService.svc/User(1)?$format=json` notice the addition of (1) which is an example of a resource identifier. Your id's may be different so check your database for a valid id.

Comment: PUT/POST need a message body - you can't update a resource without including the data about that resource. PUT (and DELETE) will need an identifier (n) in the URI.

Comment: For POST, now it says "{"odata.error":{"code":"","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The URI 'http://192.168.1.4/TestdataService/TestDataService.svc/User(1)?$format=json' is not valid for POST operation. For POST operations, the URI must refer to a service operation or an entity set."}}}

Comment: For PUT it says "{"odata.error":{"code":"","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Unsupported media type requested."}}}"

Comment: why a down-vote now??

Comment: +1 for a well elaborated question (ignoring the technical lacking)..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have two unrelated problems here. The `PUT` and `DELETE` verbs must refer to a specific entity, not an entity set. When you are `PUT`-ting to `TestDataService.svc/User`, that's like trying to update the entire entity set, which isn't allowed. Instead, you need to specify which entity you want to update (for example, by `PUT`-ting to `TestDataService.svc/User(0)`, or however the keys look for your entity set).

The `POST` problem is different. In the `POST` case you *should* be targeting the entity set instead of an invidivual entity. The error you're getting is related to the `Content-Type` or `Accept` header of the request. For now (to simpify debugging), I would leave off the `$format=json` parameter in the URI, since that overrides the `Accept` header. Try including the following header values in the `POST` request:

```
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
DataServiceVersion: 3.0;
MinDataServiceVersion: 3.0;
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0;
```

And let us know if you're still getting an error.

Again, this `POST` request should be going to `TestDataService.svc/User`, like you had originally. `PUT` and `DELETE` should point to individual entities (e.g., `TestDataService.svc/User(0)`)

Also, as qujck points out in a comment above, in your screenshots, the request body for PUT and POST are empty. POST means "insert this entry", so you need to provide an entry to be inserted in the body of the request. PUT means "replace/update this entry", so you need to provide data to the server in that case as well.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the difference between Post and Put, I didn't know the former targeted a collection and the latter an individual entity

Comment: Is it necessary to specify all fields when making update via PUT?